# Find the host header value of the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

How can i find the host header value of the website which will be give in the IIS?
i just want to display that host header name in the browser.
how can i get that value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

host header is embedded in the HTTP header section as HOST. If you want to display that in your own ASP.NET page, you can access that from Page.Context.Request.Headers.GetValues("Host")

Comment: Request.Headers["Host"] is a shorter way to do it